# ITMS-90086 "Missing 64-bit support" Error when uploading Adobe Air application to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, actionscript

I have an Adobe Air based app which I have previously uploaded using application loader to itunes connect.

Today I get the error: ERROR ITMS-90086 "Missing 64-bit support" iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with iOS 8 SDK or later.

This is odd because the 64 bit requirement has existed for some time and I am using the same build method has been accepted previously.

I have tried building without extensions to rule out third party extensions. I have updated to the latest Air SDK and are using new certificate/provisioning profiles.

I have also tried upgrading from Flash Builder 4.6 to 4.7.

Any ideas what changed?

Answer (score 1):

The reason, after much testing, is that the error is wrong and in fact the binary is fine.

The error is caused because Application Loader 3.0 has an issue. Application Loader 3.1 works OK, you do however need a much newer mac to run it.